# Change visibility timeout for an SQS message using ruby aws-sdk [ruby newbie]

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

could someone help with an example how to change visibility timeout for an sqs message using ruby aws-sdk ?

here is the code that I've used for my tests using the method batch_change_message_visibility, but I get the error "undefined method 'batch_change_message_visibility'"

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'aws-sdk'

sqs = AWS::SQS.new(
    :access_key_id => access_key,
    :secret_access_key => access_secret)

queue = sqs.queues.named(queue_name)

messages = []
messages << { :message => message_handle, :visibility_timeout => 5 }
queue.batch_change_message_visibility(messages)
```

Any Idea? Any help would the very welcome :)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the splat operator when passing the messages array parameter to the batch_change_message_visibility method.

As shown in the docs [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/SQS/Queue.html#batch_change_visibility-instance_method), you should write (note the * before the messages parameter):

```
messages = []
messages << { :message => 'handle1', :visibility_timeout => 5 }
messages << { :message => 'handle2', :visibility_timeout => 10 }

queue.batch_change_visibility(*messages)
```